# Get Counts using Linq to SQL

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have the following SQL which works fine

```
SELECT 
    f.ForumId, 
    f.Name, 
    COUNT(ft.TopicId) AS TotalTopics, 
    COUNT(fm.MessageId) AS TotalMessages
FROM 
    tblForumMessages fm INNER JOIN
    tblForumTopics ft ON fm.TopicId = ft.TopicId RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    tblForums f ON ft.ForumId = f.ForumId
GROUP BY f.ForumId, f.Name
```

That I'm trying to convert to Linq.

Here's what I have

```
 var forums =   (from f in Forums
                join ft in ForumTopics on f.ForumId equals ft.ForumId into topics
                from y in topics.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join fm in ForumMessages on y.TopicId equals fm.TopicId into messages
                from x in messages.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new { f.ForumId, f.Name, y.TopicId, x.MessageId } into x
                group x by new { x.ForumId, x.Name } into g
                select new
                    {
                        ForumId = g.Key.ForumId,
                        ForumName = g.Key.Name,
                        TopicCount = g.Count(i => i.TopicId),
                        MessageCount = g.Count(i => i.MessageId)
                    }
                ).ToList();
```

I'm getting an error on `TopicCount = g.Count(i => i.TopicId)` saying Cannot convert expression type 'System.Guid' to return type 'bool'.

What am I missing to make this work?

Thanks

* EDIT ***

Thanks to Rob I got it to work but the counts were always returning 1 for Topic Count and Message Count even though there were no records. It should have been returning 0 for both.

I've modified the query by changing

```
select new { f.ForumId, f.Name, y.TopicId, x.MessageId } into x
```

to

```
select new
{
    f.ForumId, f.Name, 
    TopicId = y != null ? y.TopicId : (Guid?)null,
    MessageId = z != null ? z.MessageId : (Guid?)null
} into x
```

And for the actual counts, I changed the query to

```
select new
{
    g.Key.ForumId,
    g.Key.Name,
    TopicCount = g.Count(t => t.TopicId != null),
    MessageCount = g.Count(t => t.MessageId != null)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offending article is `TopicCount = g.Count(i => i.TopicId)`.  The `Count` method takes a `Func<T, bool>` (it gives the number of items in the collection that satisfy the predicate).

It looks like you want the number of distinct `TopicId`s in your group.  Try replacing `TopicCount = g.Count(i => i.TopicId)` with `TopicCount = g.GroupBy(i => i.TopicId).Count()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `TopicCount = g.Select(i => i.TopicId).Distinct().Count()`